# How to say "A has X, and B has X" in a single clause

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, parallelism

How can we say

> Mike has an apple, and Jane has an apple

in a single clause? Can I say

> Both Mike and Jane have an apple

or

> Mike and Jane each have an apple?

They sound fine to me but I am not sure. Is there any alternative?

> Each of Mike and Jane has an apple

might sound too complicated.

Comment: Off topic (writing advice). See: [FAQ]

Comment: All are fine except for the last.

Answer (score 3):

"Mike and Jane each have an apple." is unambiguous and means what you want.

"Both Mike and Jane have an apple." is somewhat ambiguous. It would usually be interpreted to mean what you want. It could, however, also mean that together they share one apple.

Comment: Thanks! How about "Mike and Jane both have an apple"? Is this exactly the same as "both Mike and Jane ..."?

Comment: I disagree. In *"Both Mike and Jane have an apple"*, the mere presence of the word *both* strongly implies that they have one apple *each*. The ambiguity only arises when *both* is omitted.

Comment: edited based on @FumbleFingers comment. I agree that with apples it would usually be interpreted as two apples, one for each of them.

Comment: @Xantix: It would be the same if ***both** Mike and Jane had* almost anything, I think - they'd each have a separate *and* different one. They could only be supposed to jointly own the the same single thing with something like *"Both Mike and Jane have a duty of care towards their baby"*. And even their I'd say strictly speaking they'd each have their own responsibilities, albeit effectively identical ones.

Comment: I have to disagree with @FumbleFingers.  Mathematicians and lawyers can be particular finicky in such a situation.  Consider saying "Both have the apple" versus "Both have an apple".  Since in the first there's clearly only one apple, I'd suggest that implies that in the second it's not *necessarily* clear that is more than *one* apple.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was trying to think up an ambiguous example, but none were forthcoming. The combination of "a" and "both" seem to imply duplicity. "Both Mike and Jane have the apple" (shared).  "Mike and Jane have an apple" (shared). "Both of them have an apple" (probably not shared).

Comment: @Xantix: I rest my case! :)

Comment: @A.Ellett: Mathematicians and lawyers are not adjudicating here. But I agree changing *"a"* to *"the"* forces an almost overwhelming implication that there's only ***one*** of "it", which they have jointly. Except maybe with *"Both Mike and Jane have the time to see you today. Which one would you like to see first?"*, or some such.

Comment: *Both Mike and Jane have apples*?

Comment: "Both Mike and Jane have apples" (Mike has more than one apple, Jane has more than one apple, not shared).